# "About Me" missing - SharePoint onPremise

Tags: 2013, user-profile, my-site, user-profile-service, site

I am using SP Server onPremise, I have a site collection with some sites.

I do not see the **"About me"** menu.

I would like to allow user to change profile picture and update some information about the user. On the user profile those fields are editable.

Where is About me (my site) page?

Comment: On your SharePoint server, could you open *Services* and check whether the following tasks are running: `Forefront Identity Manager Service` and `Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service`.

Comment: they are both running

Comment: can you access this page...http://url of mysite/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/person.aspx ?

Comment: Are you using a custom master page?

Comment: yes, it is a custom master page

Comment: @NkSP Check to see if they added `.s4-socialdata-notif { 

display:none; 

}` to that Master Page.  It will hide the control.

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate the Farm-level Feature: `Social Tags and Note Board Ribbon Controls`

Once that feature is enabled, the "About Me" will replace "My Settings" in the dropdown under your Username.

Comment: This works for Central Admin, however my other web applications remain unaffected by this change... Most likely to other social features being switched off... Not sure just yet.

Comment: Do you have User Profile Service deployed? Do you have the Managed Metadata Service installed?

Comment: Specifically you should look at the Service Connections for your web applications.

Comment: I redeployed the UPS application, Self service site collection creation is disabled, User permissions have all permissions disabled (create personal site, follow people and edit profile, use tags and notes) as I only want a profile page with no social features. Service Application Associations are set to default and include the UPS application. Mysites options are set to not enable mysites activities in newfeeds. Everything that can be disabled has been disabled.
One of these options kills the "About Me" link somehow. I just need to know which one.

MMD service is deployed, although default

Comment: Note that this is not an answer to this question if it is SharePoint 2016.  This feature has been retired:  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sharepoint-online-tags-notes-feature-retired-77851bd5-6d5e-42fe-9bf6-d7c17eeb771f